# MS Excel: Nesting SUBSTITUTE & CONCATENATE Formula within Text String

Tags: excel-formula, concatenation, substitution

I would like to know if it's possible using MS Excel Formula to combine a nested SUBSTITUTE or REPLACE and CONCATENATE formula to add/insert a Character within text string

I have a column containing Keywords (Cell: A2:A3) that I would like to place a unique character ("$") in front of each of the keywords discovered within the text.

Keywords:
A2: New York, NY
A3: (250) 888-0000

OLD TEXT (Cell: B2)
John X. Doe New York, NY (250) 888-0000 johndoe@myemail.com

OUTPUT TEXT (Cell: C2)
John X. Doe $New York, NY $(250) 888-0000 johndoe@myemail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. In C2 enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,CONCATENATE("$",A2)),A3,CONCATENATE("$",A3))
```

which gives the desired output.

Comment: John, thank you very much, I'm dancing in my chair... after more than a day of trying, you solved within 2 minutes.. still dancing in my chair - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,"$"&A2),A3,"$"&A3)
```

Comment: Thank you EEM, your provided formula definitely works - thanks, as John indicated you have the method - it works.